# sed+text on a specific line after an IP

Tags: sed, line

I have the following line in my proftpd log (line 78 to be precise)

```
Deny from 1.2.3.4
```

I also have a script which rolls through my logs for people using brute force attacks and then stores their IP (ready for a black listing). What i'm struggling with is inserting (presume with sed) at the end of that specific line - this is what I've got so far:

```
sed "77i3.4.5.6" /opt/etc/proftpd.conf >> /opt/etc/proftpd.conf
```

Now one would presume this would work perfectly, however it actually does the following (lines 77 through 78):

```
3.4.5.6
Deny from 1.2.3.4
```

I suspect this is due to my dated version of sed, are there any other ways of acheiving the same thing? Also the >> causes the config to be duplicated at the end of the fole (again i'm sure this is a limitation of my version of sed). This is running a homebrew linux kernel on my nas. Sed options below:

> root@NAS:~# sed BusyBox v1.7.0
>   (2009-04-29 19:12:57 JST) multi-call
>   binary
>
> Usage: sed [-efinr] pattern [files...]
>
> Options:
>           -e script       Add the script to the commands to be executed
>           -f scriptfile   Add script-file contents to the
>                           commands to be executed
>           -i              Edit files in-place
>           -n              Suppress automatic printing of pattern space
>           -r              Use extended regular expression syntax
>
> If no -e or -f is given, the first
>   non-option argument is taken as the
>   sed script to interpret. All remaining
>   arguments are names of input files; if
>   no input files are specified, then the
>   standard input is read. Source files
>   will not be modified unless -i option
>   is given.

Cheers for your help guys.

Answer (score 2):

This has nothing to do with the version of sed; this is just plain old Doing It Wrong.

```
sed -i '77s/$/,3.4.5.6/' /opt/etc/proftpd.conf
```

Comment: You bloody smart arse, thanks. Would you mind explaining this a bit? Is it just a case of a search on line 77 and then replaching '$' (presume this means nothing) with back ticked IP address?

Comment: `$` is the end of the string/line. So this basically just appends the address to the end of line 77. Also, `s` is substitute, not search.